# What is the Synchronization context In Java

Tags: java, synchronization

All of you know the synchronization context in Java that they are can be

- on the instance.
- on the java.lang.Class instance for a certain loaded class.
- on a given object

And I need to ask; When i write

```
Dimension d = new Dimension();

synchronized(d){
  // critical atomic operation
}
```

synchronization of a given object equal to synchronization on the instance practically.

so when I write *synchronized(d)* where *d* is an instance of object, then the thread will gain the lock for all synchronized instance block of code.

Can you please give me more details about synchronization context.

Your replies will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

The `synchronized` keyword provides serial access to the block of code (which could be an entire method) it introduces. Serialization of access is done by using an object as a [mutex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion) lock.

The three basic uses of `synchronized` are:

A. On a static method:

```
static synchronized void someStaticMethod() {
   // The Class object - ie "MyClass.class" - is the lock object for this block of code, which is the whole method
}
```

B. On an instance method:

```
synchronized void someInstanceMethod() {
   // The instance - ie "this" - is lock object for this block of code, which is the whole method
}
```

C. On an arbitrary block of code:

```
private Object lock = new Object();
void someMethod() {
    synchronized (lock) {
        // The specified object is the lock object for this block of code
    }
}
```

In all cases, only one thread at a time may enter the synchronized block.

In all cases, if the same lock object is used for *multiple* blocks, only one thread may enter *any* of the synchronised blocks. For example, if there are two - other simultaneous threads calling the methods will block until the first thread exits the method.

Comment: Good, lets focus on the third type of lock which methods will be locked in the lock object. static methods or instance synchronization (methods or blocks) or both of them? for my first impression the instance synchronization will be the correct answer.

Comment: I think you are a little confused Mohammed, nothing is locked in the **lock** object itself. That object is used as a mutex lock to synchronize the part inside the `{...}`. Using a lock object, instead of the implicit synchronization (A. and B. above), allows us to have finer grained control. For example, readers could all have one kind of lock, and writers another etc.

Comment: In Java, the synchronization is achieved by locking an object. so which of the following object gets lock in the C ? sure not this instance and not X.class but the answer will be the "lock" object itself in C option. based on your mutex document there is a resource common and that resource must be safe from simultaneous access. Correct me please.

Comment: The lock on an object is done by the JVM, but what you are talking about is a use for object lock. you don't talk about synchronized mechanism. Java Certificate talks about that in the objective 4.3 in SCJP.

Answer (score 2):

Applying the synchronized keyword to a non-static method is shorthand for:

```
public void method() {
    synchronized(this) {
        // method
    }
}
```

If you apply `synchronized` to a static method, then it locks the class object (MyClass.class) whilst the method is called.

Comment: I don't think that, for locking static methods you need to lock java.lang.Class instance for the class loaded by synchronized(X.class). the synchronized(this) will locking the synchronization blocks in the instance.

Comment: Sorry @Mohammed Amr, right you are, and I knew that as well, just was rushed off to something else as I was typing.  Corrected.